# how to make multi selector or multi id for Copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, clipboard

I like so much to have a copy to clipboard in my website, here the example which I interesting it.

```
(function() {

    "use strict";

    function copyToClipboard(elem) {

        var target = elem;

        // select the content
        var currentFocus = document.activeElement;

        target.focus();
        target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);
        // copy the selection
        var succeed;

        try {
            succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn(e);
            succeed = false;
        }
        // Restore original focus
        if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
            currentFocus.focus();
        }

        if (succeed) {
            $(".copied").animate({
                top: -25,
                opacity: 0
            }, 700, function() {
                $(this).css({
                    top: 0,
                    opacity: 1
                });
            });
        }
        return succeed;
    }

    $("#copyButton, #copyTarget").on("click", function() {

        copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("copyTarget"));
    });
}());
```

Here is the codepen https://codepen.io/LattyS/pen/QvGyKL

But I have 2 problems with it

1. when trying to make more than 1 link if I click any one all of them copied together.
2. how can create DIV too

So I need to make more than 10 links at the same time, and if there ability to use the copy to clipboard with DIV too or not with the same project? like this one in the image https://gulfupload.com/i/00025/fq8kg0ef7gw6.png

Answer (score 1):

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    function copyToClipboard(elem) {

        var target = elem;

        // select the content
        var currentFocus = document.activeElement;

        target.focus();
        target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);

        // copy the selection
        var succeed;

        try {

            succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
        } catch (e) {

            console.warn(e);

            succeed = false;
        }

        // Restore original focus
        if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {

            currentFocus.focus();
        }

        if (succeed) {

            $(target).closest('.input-group').find('.copied').animate({top: -25, opacity: 0}, 700, function () {

                $(this).css({top: 0, opacity: 1});
            });
        }

        return succeed;
    }


    $(".copyButton").on("click", function () {

        var parent = $(this).closest('.input-group');

        copyToClipboard(parent.find(".copyTarget")[0]);
    });
}());
```

Codepen link for copying single link at a time from multiple links: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ELXWaG

Comment: any way thanks , BUT , why the yellow color does not appear and too active mouse does not work when you button  and 2left click over the text too does not work right now?